# Is It Possible To Apply Rules To a Specific Tag In a Nest Of Tags?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

this is a pretty, what i think unusual kind of problem i would like to get solved.

This is about accessing a specific html tag in css. So here is the scenario in the html file

```
<DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
      <head>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="MyCssCode.css"/>
      </head>
      <body>
         <p>
            Some Text!
            <h1>Even More Text!</h1> <!-- what i want to access -->
         </p>
         <h1> Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet.</h1>
      </body> 
   </html>
```

Now the problem comes when in css, i want to specificaly apply a rule to the `h1` that is inside of the `p` tag. Without affecting the other `h1` that is below (outside the p tag). i have tried selectors such as `+` and `>` but i can't find a real answer on this online prooving this is impossible or not.

Comment: `<hx>` inside a `<p>` is invalid HTML. Odds are that when you test your CSS the browser is rearranging the elements to make it valid. But if it was valid, `p > h1` would work

Comment: You can different classes to the elements and access them that way, you will need to construct the whole H1 look but it will get you what you want easily.

Comment: @j08691 Oh okay. That actually explains alot, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because is inappropriate put h1 tag inside of p tag, if you look in browser console you can see your code broken.

[image]

Instead of using p tag, you can use div tag like this

```
<html >
<body>
    <div>
        Some Text!
        <h1>Even More Text!</h1> <!-- what i want to access -->
    </div>
    <h1> Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet.</h1>
</body>
```

An then you can apply styles like this

```
div h1{/* all h1 tag inside div*/}
div+h1{/* the h1 next to div*/}
div>h1{ /* h1 tags direct child of a div*/}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve this because a `h1` tag cannot be inside a `p`.

If you replace the `p` with a `div`, it works just fine :

```css
div h1 {
  color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="MyCssCode.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    Some Text!
    <h1>Even More Text!</h1>
    <!-- what i want to access -->
  </div>
  <h1> Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet.</h1>
</body>

</html>
```